# show the row with max groupby with two columns sql

Tags: sql, group-by, oracle-sqldeveloper

lots of variations of this questions have been asked but can't seem to find the right one for my table.  i have three columns pd, stm, and salesincrease.  i want to find the max of salesincrease for each stm.

```
  pd        stm    salesincrease
Chamomile   Central 801
Caffe Mocha Central 752
Earl Grey   Central 725
Colombian   East    975
Lemon       East    573
RegEspresso East    531
Caffe Mocha East    356
Lemon       West    667
DeEspresso  West    664
Colombian   West    628
Darjeeling  West    623
```

The problem I am getting is that i do:

```
select  stm, pd, max(salesincrease) as maxsales from
table
group by stm, pd;
```

and it doesn't show the right results.  I also tried:

```
select  stm, max(salesincrease) as maxsales from
table
group by stm;
```

This obviously shows the stm and max but i can't get the product name in there without an error

Ideally I want an output like this:

```
  pd        stm    salesincrease
Chamomile   Central 801
Colombian   East    975
Lemon       West    667
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `row_number()`:

```
select pd, stm, salesincrease
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by stm order by salesincrease desc) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: `partition by stm` I think

Answer (score 0):

The following query should return the results your looking for:

```
WITH maxsalesincrease AS
(
SELECT stm, max(salesincrease) AS maxsales
FROM table
GROUP BY stm
)
SELECT t.pd, t.stm, t.sales
FROM table t, maxsalesincrease s
WHERE t.salesincrease = s.maxsales
    AND t.stm = s.stm
```

This creates a CTE that gets us the stm with the maxsalesincrease for that stm.  Then we join that back to our original table where the salesincrease is equal to maxsales and the stms match.  This will also correctly return results if two pds in the same stm have the same largest max(salesincrease).